# Athena Simple Unload and Count Queries Running for Long Time and Going in Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-athena

I have multiple Athena Queries running around 100 at a time but most of the queries are taking longer amount of time to complete and sometime even going in a queues and failing saying Throttling Exceeded.

Queries Used :

- UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM table where col1 = value and col2=value and col3=value )
  TO 's3://my_athena_data_location/my_folder/'
  WITH (field delimeter ='|',format='TEXTFILE')
- Select count(1) from table where col1 = value and col2=value and col3=value.

There are multiple tables partitioned on 3 common columns(col1,col2,col3). Above queries are running for multiple table simultaneously.

I have checked Service Quotas for Athena Service - Active DDL Queries is set to - 20 and Active DML Queries set to - 150

Can someone please help how we can improve the execution performance.